# Reg ex involving new line for Powershell script

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a long text file that looks like this:

```
("B3501870","U00357"),
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Bnumbers] VALUES
("B3501871","U11019"),
("B3501899","U28503"),
```

I want every line before INSERT to end not with , but with ; instead.
So the end result should look like this:

```
("B3613522","U00357");
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Bnumbers] VALUES
("B3615871","U11019"),
("B3621899","U28503"),
```

I tried multiple ways to achieve this but it does not appear to work with multiple lines.
One way I tried was like this:

```
(Get-Content -path C:\temp\bnr\list.sql -Raw) -replace ",\nINSERT", ";\nINSERT" | Add-Content -Path C:\temp\bnr\test.sql
```

Tried with

```
[io.file]::ReadAllText("C:\temp\bnr\list.sql")
```

hoping it treat the file as one giant string but to no avail.

Any way to tell PS to find comma+newline+INSERT and do changes to it?

```
,\nINSERT
```

works on Sublime text with reg ex but not in PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(Get-Content -path C:\temp\bnr\list.sql -Raw) -replace ',(\r?\nINSERT)', ';$1'
```

Or,

```
(Get-Content -path C:\temp\bnr\list.sql -Raw) -replace ',(?=\r?\nINSERT)', ';'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e4TjOg/1).

The `,(?=\r?\nINSERT)` regex matches a comma that is immediately followed with an optional CR char, then LF char, then `INSERT` text. The `,(\r?\nINSERT)` variation captures the CRLF/LF ending + `INSERT` string into Group 1, hence the `$1` backreference in the replacement pattern that puts this text back into the result.

Comment: And to think I struggled with this entire day. I thank you, good sir!!!